# Conflicting click and hover events on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a refresh "button" (actually a png image) which the user can hover their mouse over, turning it from gray to blue. When refresh is clicked, the image changes to a play "button" which exhibits similar color-changing behavior, except when you click on the play image it should switch back to the original refresh image.

The problem is that, after clicking on the refresh image, when I click on the play image without removing my mouse from the image, it doesn't change back to the refresh image.

I have already looked into event propagation stopping.

Here is my code:

```
$('#refresh').click(function (event) {
    if (!tMinusZero) {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='play_small_hover.png'>");
        tMinusZero = true;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } else {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='refresh_small_hover.png'>");
        tMinusZero = false;(
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});

$('#refresh').hover(function () {
    if (!tMinusZero) {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='refresh_small_hover.png'>");
    } else {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='play_small_hover.png'>");
    }
}, function () {
    if (!tMinusZero) {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='refresh_small.png'>");
    } else {
        $('#refresh').html("<img src='play_small.png'>");
    }
});
```

Some interesting things I have noticed whilst trying to debug:

- If I move my mouse through #refresh too fast the hover will 'stick' i.e. the implicit mouseleave won't fire.
- Commenting out the hover code fixes the clicking problem.
- Leaving the hover code in, if I click outside of the image but inside of the div, without removing my mouse from the div, fixes the clicking problem.
- Removing my mouse from the div before trying to click again fixes the clicking problem.
- After clicking on the image, the image it changes to will flicker between the hover and non-hover image if I move my mouse over it, but not if I first remove my mouse from the div.
- When I experience the clicking problem, the offending image will flicker momentarily, as if switching to one of the non-hover images, and then quickly changing back to the offending image.

It seems to me that my two event handlers have conflicting interests, but stopping the event propagation doesn't seem to help.

Comment: can you make a demo over here.? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: The problem does not happens to me (http://jsfiddle.net/45R95/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ah, yes. I will for sure next time. I was hoping this would be a simple semantic fix and didn't bother creating a fiddle for others to mess around with. Good call.

Comment: @chumkiu I think there might have been something strange with the fact that I was using a png image. Like a mentioned above, clicking within the div but not on the image, my code worked fine. Thanks for the sanity check, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to tackle your problem with CSS, i think it will be more elegant, make a small DIV, with a background corresponding to your image, define a hover state and an active state, plus a small script to change between 2 more additional states

Something like:
CSS:

```
#refresh[data-state=notclicked]
{
background-image:url('play_small.png');
cursor:pointer;
}
#refresh[data-state=notclicked]:hover
{
background-image:url('play_small_hover.png');
cursor:pointer;
}
#refresh[data-state=clicked]
{
background-image:url('refresh_small.png');
cursor:pointer;
}
#refresh[data-state=clicked]:hover
{
background-image:url('refresh_small_hover.png');
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Of course you will have to define the width and the height in the CSS, to a fixed width.height which matches your png size.

Than the js:

```
$("#refresh").click(function(){
if ($(this).attr('data-state')=='clicked') {$(this).attr('data-state','notclicked');}
else  {$(this).attr('data-state','clicked');}
});
```

Comment: OMG you are like the Mother Teresa of the Internet. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly how you want it to behave, your code seems to work just fine, even though there's a typo in the click event (round bracket).

```
tMinusZero = false;(
```

Also, just for improve the code you can replace

```
$('#refresh')
```

with

```
$(this)
```

inside the event as it'll refer to the dom element you attached the event to.